# http request going over https server in laravel ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, mixed-content

[image]I am trying to get some data using ajax in laravel project.
i have https domain but when the ajax request is made it is made over http.
So the ajax request gives a mixed content error and also a https request for same is showed cancelled.

i have already added to app service provider

```php
if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
  \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

main ajax setup with url formation

```
let url = '/opportunities/?' + $('#opportunity_search_form').serialize();
if(window.location.search && !this.initialLoaded){
   url = url + '&' +window.location.search.substring(1);
}
url = url + '&page=' + self.pageCtr
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "get",
  beforeSend: function(xhr, type) {
    if (!type.crossDomain) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    }
  }
})
```

in the above image first request that shows cancelled goes over https ... and the other goes over http with mixed content error..i don't know how it is being sent .
Also i tried creating url using

```
let url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/opportunties/' + other parameters
```

Thankyou.

Comment: The devtools screenshot seems to indicate the request is getting redirected from the https URL to the equivalent http URL. Have you tried manually opening that same https URL in your browser? Does it redirect to http when you do that?

Comment: No it doesnt redirect

Comment: A very weird fix that worked was removing / from before starting query string i.e. Opportunities?query=asda worked instead of opportunities/?query=asda

Answer (score 0):

You can enable force HTTPS by using the following code on AppServiceProvider's boot function.

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {    
  $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on'); 
}
```